# Tail -f | Grep <regex> | php script.php <grep result>

Tags: php, bash, ssh, grep, pipe

Ok, so I have a ssh connection open to a remote server.  I'm running a tail on the logs and if an ID shows up in the logs I need to do an insert into the database.

So I have my ssh tail working and I have it piping into my grep function which is giving me the IDs I need.  The next step is that as those IDs are found it needs to immediately kick off a php script.

What I thought it would look like is:

`ssh -t <user>@<host> "tail -f /APP/logs/foo.log" | grep -oh "'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'" | php myscript.php <grep result>`

And yes my regex is horrible, wanted to use [0-9]{8}, but what I have gets the job done.

Any suggestions?  Tried looking at -exec, awk, or any other tool.  I could write the result to its own file and then read the new file, but that doesn't catch the streaming ids.

-=-=-=-=-EDIT-=-=-=-=-=-

So here is what I'm using:

`ssh -t <user>@<host> "tail -f /APP/logs/foo.log" |grep "^javax.ejb.ObjectNotFoundException"  |awk '/[0-9]/ { system("php myscript.php  "$6) }'`

And if I use `tail -l #lines` it works, or if after a while I ctrl-c, it then works.  The behavior I wanted though was to as the tail got a bad ID to kick off the script to fix the bad ID.  Not wait until an EOF or some tail buffer...

Comment: `ssh -t user@host sh -c "tail -f /path | grep -oh 'pattern'"` ...

Comment: if you want to use the output of a command as a php argument then try this:
`php myscript.php '[command]'`

NOTE: Those ticks MUST be backticks ` I just couldn't figure out how to escape them so they would properly show.

Comment: @user2537383 If possible he should use $() instead of the backticks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problem. There's something funny with tail -f and grep -o combination when ssh.

So on local server, if you do

```
tail -f myfile.log |grep -o keyword
```

It grep just fine.

But if you do it from remote server....

```
ssh user@server 'tail -f myfile.log |grep -o keyword'
```

doesn't work

But if you remove -f from tail or -o from grep, work just fine... weird :-/